# DropDownList.DataTextField can't be bound to a dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to bind a `dataset` to a `dropdownlist`, which throws a `HttpException`

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
if (dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //Bind dataset to new group selection
    ddlNewGroup.DataSource = dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    ddlNewGroup.DataValueField = "band_id";
    ddlNewGroup.DataTextField = "band_naam";
    ddlNewGroup.DataBind();
}
else
{
    ddlNewGroup.Items.Add(new ListItem("No groups to add"));
}
```

The exception message:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'band_naam'.
```

I'm absolutely positive that the `dataset` contains a column with the title band_naam. As you can see, the exception is thrown when binding the `DataTextField`, meaning that the `DataValueField` is bound correctly, right?

EDIT:

This is the stored procedure:

```
USE [groep2_festivals]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetGroupsOfFestival]    Script Date: 14-05-13 12:31:18 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Robbie Vercammen
-- Create date: 2013-05-09
-- Description: Getting all groups for a defined festival
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGroupsOfFestival]
    (
    @festId  nvarchar(4)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query varchar(255)

    SELECT b.*, p.* 
    FROM bands b 
    JOIN bandsperfestival bpf ON b.band_id = bpf.band_id 
    JOIN podia p ON p.pod_id = bpf.pod_id WHERE fest_id LIKE @festId
    EXEC(@query)
END
```

Notice the `b.*` and `bands b`?
Now here that table:

[image]

This stored procedure has been used on multiple occasions, so I'm pretty sure that it works correctly. But here's perhaps the most important code that I forgot to mention:

```
//Filling dataset with groups not on this festival
dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
foreach (DataRow row in dsGroupsAll.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (!dsGroupsPerFestival.Tables[0].Rows.Equals(row))
    {
        dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].ImportRow(row);
    }
}
```

And once again, the `DataSet` dsGroupsAll has been used before so the data is present :)

@manish mishra
dsGroupsAll is filled with the same stored procedure above.
To prove that there is actually data in there:

[image]

For those still following, I've confirmed that there are 14 rows in `dsGroupsNotOnFestival`.
When i'm trying to get a value in a simple way, for example:

```
String strResult = dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

I get an exception saying that column 0 could not be found... why is that?

Comment: instead of `dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].DefaultView` as datasource, specify the table only like `dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0]`

Comment: Check if there's any trailing space in column name in `DataSet`.

Comment: Is the code running when you comment // ddlNewGroup.DataTextField = "band_naam"; ?

Comment: I'll give that a try, don't know why i haven't thought about earlier

Comment: @Serge, you're right... even though the value field is bound first it still gives me the error on the text field. When commenting it out, I get the same error on the value field, any ideas?

Comment: Such databinding uses Properies only. I don't really know how C# do the inner work when using DataSet/Tables/View but maybe you could try: ddlNewGroup.DataSource = dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();

Comment: No sorry, that didn't change a thing :(

Comment: I feel stupid for asking, but does it matter if I do this in the dropdownlist prerendering event?

Comment: I've edited my post. Please read the last few lines

Comment: Do not use DataSet, use DataReader instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm absolutely positive that the dataset contains a column with the title band_naam.

I understand how you feel, but **I'm absolutely positive that there isn't one** because that error is extremely explicit:

> does not contain a property with the name 'band_naam'

Have another look at the code that fills that `DataSet`. The `DefaultView` is a perfect image of the `DataTable`, which of course is the result set of your query, so the query you're using to fill this `DataTable` is missing this field.

**Maybe it's a calculated field and you forgot the `AS` keyword to give it a column name.**

---

## EDIT

Based on your feedback (i.e. screenshots of the queries and schema), I'm going to say Habib probably hit it right on the head in the comments, change this line:

```
ddlNewGroup.DataSource = dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

to this line:

```
ddlNewGroup.DataSource = dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0];
```

I personally have never had a problem binding to a `DefaultView` but I don't feel there are any other possibilities left.

Comment: No, the table that contains band_naam definitely there. I'll post the stored procedure and an image of the table that is relevant. Thanks for the help so far. If you need more info let me know

Comment: @RobbieVercammen, what's the structure of `podia` look like?

Comment: three columns: pod_id int, pod_omschr nvarchar(255), pod_locatie nvarchar(255)

Comment: When I'm sure that I have a dataset with only one table I normally bind the dataset without the .Tables[0] declaration and it works as well

Comment: @RobbieVercammen why don't you simply debug and inspect .Tables[0]? there is nothing wrong with dropdown or c#. It has to be your sp and table. use a breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am allowed to approve my own answers, but I found the solution to my nightmare.

```
//Filling dataset with groups not on this festival
dsGroupsNotOnFestival = dsGroupsPerFestival.Clone();
foreach (DataRow row in dsGroupsAll.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (!dsGroupsPerFestival.Tables[0].Rows.Equals(row))
    {
        dsGroupsNotOnFestival.Tables[0].ImportRow(row);
    }
}
```

The difference is, I'm cloning the original `DataSet` preserving the structure, constraints, etc using:

```
dsGroupsPerFestival.Clone()
```

Thanks everyone for helping me out!

Comment: You can select your own answer as the correct one if you believe that it is the best solution posted.